# let $\phi \subset C[0,1]$ be the set $\phi =\{f\in C^1[0,1]: \int^1_0 |f'(x)|^3dx\le 7\}$ prove that $\phi$ is equicontinous

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity

let $\phi \subset C[0,1]$ be the set $\phi =\{f\in C^1[0,1]: \int^1_0 |f'(x)|^3dx\le 7\}$ prove that $\phi$ is equicontinous

**Def (Equicontunous ):**

A collection of functions on $\phi \subset C[0,1]$ Equicontunous  if given $\epsilon>0$
there exist $\delta>0$ such that whenever $x,y\in \phi$ satisfy $d(x,y)<\delta, |\phi(x)-\phi(y)|<\epsilon$

how to proceed with this?

sorry I'm not getting  any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of equicontinuity is confused. Here is a more precise statement of (uniform) equicontinuity: a family $\mathcal{F}\subset C[0,1]$ is uniformly equicontinuous if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that, whenever $x,y\in[0,1]$ satisfy $d(x,y)<\delta$, then $d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$ for all $f\in \mathcal{F}$.

Now, let $f\in\mathcal{F}$ as defined in your question; suppose $x\leq y$ so the fundamental theorem of calculus gives us the estimate
$$|f(y) - f(x)| = \left|\int_x^yf'(t)\,dt\right|\leq \int_x^y |f'(t)|\,dt.$$
From here we need to somehow relate the integral of $|f'|$ to the integral of $|f'|^3$. This should naturally bring to mind the [Hölder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality). We use exponents $p=3$ and $q=3/2$ to find
$$\int_x^y |f'(t)|\cdot 1\,dt\leq \left(\int_x^y|f'(t)|^3\,dt\right)^{1/3}\left(\int_x^y 1^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}\leq 7^{1/3}(y-x)^{2/3}.$$
Thus we have $|f(y)-f(x)|\leq 7^{1/3}(y-x)^{2/3}$ for $x\leq y$, which easily implies $|f(y)-f(x)|\leq 7^{1/3}|y-x|^{2/3}$ for all $x,y\in[0,1]$. Since this estimate is true for all $f\in\mathcal{F}$ equicontinuity follows, since for given $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $\delta = (\epsilon/7^{1/3})^{3/2}$.